# Post-exercise muscle soreness

Tags: muscle-soreness, muscle-recovery, sleep, timing

I’m a vigorous 72yo who enjoys pushing his limits via cycling, swimming, Pilates or weights. In the evenings on a day of a challenging 1 hr workout I will recline in my zero gravity chair to read but often fall asleep. As I enter sleep I feel a sensation of soreness in the muscle groups utilized which is very pleasurable. This is different, I think, from typical energized and happy feeling a few hours after exercise which I’ve always ascribed to endorphins. I can’t find any literature on the light-sleep related feeling. It doesn’t happen if I just go to bed.